# submit button inside iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a iframe tag inside my webpage. The iframe page(imported page ) contains a submit button. When I click this button the link loads in the same iframe area, I want to open this link as a new page other than loading in the same iframe area.

Comment: please post your html so we can see the problem.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `iframe`s?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `formtarget="_blank"` or `target="_blank"` attribute to your `button` or `input[type=button]` element.

Answer (score 0):

From the web use target attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```